# Accumulation of electrons inside vacuum tube during photoelectric effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, vacuum, photoelectric-effect

I'm thinking of the general photoelectric effect experiment set-up.

[image]

We know that after certain value of potential difference between Cathode and Anode, the photocurrent of the circuit will reach plateau and stay near constant even when you increase the potential (due to saturation current of diode).

When the diode reach its saturation current, wouldn't electrons still be able to travel up to certain point of the Anode as long as the light is shined to the Cathode (Assuming Cathode hasn't reached enough net positive charge to emit more electrons)?
What would happen to the electrons inside this vacuum tube then? Would it kind of sit around in some region? What would happen as more electron gets accumulated inside this tube?

Comment: where is the diode in your diagram, do you mean the tube with the anode and cathode? why should it have a saturation current?  Unless the vacuum stops being a vacuum?

Comment: @annav Yes, I meant the anode and cathode. So from my researching, I got that increasing the potential difference doesn't increase the photocurrent because of saturation current (maybe this was wrong).

Comment: as far as I know saturation currents are in semiconductors that have carriers both ways :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_current

Comment: @annav Okay, why does increasing the voltage not change the photocurrent from certain value?

Comment: Are you sure? the effect is measured the opposite way "Finding the opposing voltage it took to stop all the electrons gave a measure of the maximum kinetic energy of the electrons in electron volts. "  see the plot http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html . Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect#Experimental_observation_of_photoelectric_emission .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to mis-understand saturation current cause. Imagine you want a photocurrent to be about $2~C/s$, by raising a voltage even more, but given light *intensity* can knock-out from a photosensitive material only $1~C/s$. Where additional $1~\text{Coulomb}$ will come from ? So answer is simple, - voltage can only speed-up electrons at maximum rate which is the same rate at which light intensity can pluck electrons out of cathode.

Comment: So photocurrent reaches limit after certain voltage due to the limit of how much electrons photosensitive material can emit?

Comment: Not exactly. How much it can emit due to current level of **light flux** hitting cathode. Check figure 11 of [this work](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/acs.nanolett.5b00190), and you'll see that increase of a laser power gives increase in the photocurrent. So basically, it can be said that a photodevice converts light intensity into photocurrent density. An applied voltage is just some sort of "valve", which supports or extinguishes this effect.

Comment: Also, there's a nice paper in nature communications journal which analyzes [photocurrent switching effect](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-14675-5#ref-CR18) and finds-out relation between a photocurrent and a light flux, which is : $$ i = i_0\left( {1 - {\mathrm{{e}}}^{ - k\phi }} \right) .$$ Hope that helps.

Comment: Why won't voltage increase the photocurrent? Wouldn't it also increase the amount of electrons coming in since it reduces the time it takes from cathode to anode? Or is this speed difference gained from voltage negligible compared to the ejecting velocity.

Comment: How will voltage increase number of electrons if light didn't supply them more from cathode? Remember, everything starts from the action of light,- $\phi_0$ flux of light say can hit $N_0$ electrons per second out of cathode- and that's it, you can't get more even you raise voltage to the sky. But raising light intensity from $\phi_0 \to \phi_1$, where $\phi_1 \gt \phi_0$, helps, because now light frees more electrons $N_1 \gt N_0$ per second which can be speed-up by applied voltage.

Comment: In other words, it doesn't matter that if you will increase food picking speed from a hotel Smörgåsbord, but if waiters will not increase default food supply speed _to the table_,- then your quick running around empty table will not perform expected results, you will just 99% of time wait for a next dish to become available. Hope now everything is clear :-)

Comment: Can I lastly ask why voltage is can't free the electron from cathode at all? Thank you for all the answers though.

Comment: Because we are talking about [a photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect), right ? If charges are freed not by the incident electromagnetic radiation, then it's not a photoelectric effect.

Comment: You said that raising voltage to the sky still won't make electrons be ejected. Wouldn't having enough high voltage make metal spit out electrons from the electromagnetic radiation and more from the voltage difference (since metal will get polarized with voltage difference and maybe this can reduce the work function of the metal or maybe the voltage difference directly rip the electrons off the metal)?

Comment: From wiki: _The photoelectric effect is the emission of electrons when electromagnetic radiation, such as light, hits a material. Electrons emitted in this manner are called photoelectrons._ So if electrons are being emitted by other means from a cathode, then this is not a photoelectric effect. I.e. that is irrelevant to your original posted question.

Comment: I know it's not my original question. My question had an error so I started asking why the photocurrent won't go up even with voltage increase.

Comment: And I have answered you already, at least what's in the scope of photocurrent linear process. I agree that there _may_ exist some non-linear processes which can interfere with a photoelectric effect, but at this point these are speculations for which I can't say any (contra-)arguments, so I'll stop my discussion there. Maybe theoretical physicists can answer you better.

Comment: Thank you for your help.